# Merge data from excel files

Tags: excel, matlab, command-line

I have about 70,000 excel files each of size about 300kb. The first column is date and time and rest columns are all doubles.

How do I merge them into 1 single csv file or bring them all together into one sheet of an excel work book. I was thinking about using Matlab but it runs out of memory.

Comment: I think Matlab is not a good idea, if you use Matlab you have to load all the data in the workspace in order to merge it, I do not think you will able to do so, you will run out of memory before loading all the data.

Comment: Do you just want to append the files, one after the other? Or do you need to look for duplicate records and properly merge them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [RDBMerge](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm). It's a free add-in for Excel built for this sort of work.

Alternatively, you may find the following info useful:
http://ask.metafilter.com/106144/Combining-a-ton-of-Excel-files-into-one-Excel-file

Answer (score -2):

If it's a one off this is what I would do:

Copy all details from both sheets to a single sheet in a new workbook

Sort descending by your date and time column

Duplicate the data and time column on the end (For vlookup, if you are comfortable using index you can avoid this)

Duplicate the sheet

Delete the data in the date and time column

Data / Remove duplicates to get a distinct set

Use a vlookup on some referential column to get the date and time (Make the last argument in the vlookup 0)

This will pull in the first instance it finds for the data (ie the highest date / time).

Should take about 2 mins all up.